# jquery mobile document.ready vs div.live

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

When do I use  $('div').live('pageshow', function ()  in jquery mobile? Does it replace $(document).ready entirely?

```
$(document).ready(function() 

$('div').live('pageshow', function ()
```

Answer (score 4):

When you follow an internal link on your jQuery Mobile site, the page is loaded with AJAX. However, only the content (`<body>`) is loaded. Therefore, if you want to have something execute when the page is loaded, you need to use the `.live(pagecreate, function())` function.

```
$('#aboutPage').live('pagecreate',function(event){
     alert('This page was just enhanced by jQuery Mobile!');
});
```

[jQuery Mobile Documentation - Page Scripting](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/pages/page-scripting.html)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 1.5 uses in-memory caching for entire Web pages, including their JavaScript states, for a single browser session. Going backward and forward between visited pages requires no page loading and the JavaScript states are preserved. This feature, referred to by some as bfcache (for "Back-Forward Cache"), makes page navigation very fast. This caching state is preserved until the user closes the browser.

**pageshow event**

This event works the same as the `load` event, except that it fires every time the page is loaded (whereas the load event doesn’t fire in Firefox 1.5 when the page is loaded from cache). The first time the page loads, the `pageshow` event fires just after the firing of the load event. The pageshow event uses a boolean property called `persisted` that is set to `false` on the initial load. It is set to `true` if it is not the initial load (in other words, it is set to true when the page is cached).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching